# Change text of Bootstrap toggle button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have toggle button of Bootstrap which have following code:

```
<input data-no-uniform="true" type="checkbox" class="iphone-toggle">
```

When I write above code default it display `ON` and `OFF`.

My question is how to change ON/OFF to YES/NO. Is there any code to change text? I search on google but no luck.

**EDIT**

```
<div class="iPhoneCheckContainer" style="width: 94px;">
    <input class="iphone-toggle" type="checkbox" checked="" data-no-uniform="true">
    <label class="iPhoneCheckLabelOff" style="width: 89px;">
        <span style="margin-right: 0px;">OFF</span>
    </label>
    <label class="iPhoneCheckLabelOn" style="width: 4px;">
        <span style="margin-left: -50px;">ON</span>
    </label>
    <div class="iPhoneCheckHandle" style="width: 41px; left: 0px;">
        <div class="iPhoneCheckHandleRight">
            <div class="iPhoneCheckHandleCenter"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It internally generate above code when I write single line of code so how can I change it text?

Comment: Can you give me code for that in answer?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395235/change-text-of-corresponding-label-when-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked

Comment: I want to change default label ON/OFF to YES/NO when page load not on click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change the default labels using script. Add this at the bottom of your page outside of dom ready handler

```
iOSCheckbox.defaults.checkedLabel='Yes';
iOSCheckbox.defaults.uncheckedLabel='No';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it's perfect solution which I want. Thanks once again.